# Does a SASS post-fixed ampersand invert selector nesting?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to grok the following example I found on the interwebs. It looks as if post-fixing a ampersand causes SASS to invert the nesting?

```
.MyComponent {
  &-title {
    .MyComponent--xmasTheme & {
    }
  }

  &-content {
    .MyComponent--xmasTheme & {
    }
  }
}

// Compiles to
.MyComponent-title {}
.MyComponent--xmasTheme .MyComponent-title {}
.MyComponent-content {}
.MyComponent--xmasTheme .MyComponent-content {}
```

Comment: Interesting behavior, I would expect to get `.MyComponent-title .MyComponent--xmasTheme .MyComponent-title` instead of `.MyComponent--xmasTheme .MyComponent-title`...

Comment: [Here is an article about this](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand)

Comment: Aha thanks Arkellys. Since the ampersand is like a variable holding the parent block, it will output that value no matter the position of the ampersand. I think I was confused since I read ampersand as a conjunction but in the example it's used as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say that @Arkellys comments answered this for me, seeing the SASS ampersand as a variable to the nested selector's parent. So when the ampersand is post-fixed in the nested selector, that's where SASS outputs the parent selector.

Answer (score 0):

`&-title` is a SASS feature to BEM-fy your syntax. It was introduced with the version 3.3.0rc3 and replaces the old syntax `@at-root #{&}-title`.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#adding-suffixes

Interesting articles about this feature:

- https://unakravets.tumblr.com/post/78744593423/sass-snippets-the-almighty-ampersand
- http://alwaystwisted.com/articles/2014-02-27-even-easier-bem-ing-with-sass-33
- https://www.sitepoint.com/structuring-css-class-selectors-with-sass/

So this syntax:

```
.MyComponent {
  &-title {
    color:blue;
  }
}
```

create this output:

```
.MyComponent-title {
  color: blue;
}
```

and not:

```
.MyComponent .MyComponent-title {
  color: blue;
}
```

**P.S.** To create the last output you could write an amperstand with interpolation syntax:

```
.MyComponent {
  #{&}-title {
    color:blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explainer. In the example I posted, it seems as if  post-fixing the ampersand negated the need for interpolation syntax.